# How do I convert mysql spatial POINT into a readable format in a yii model?

Tags: mysql, yii, geospatial, spatial

I have a yii model that is based on a mysql table with a spatial `POINT` field.  When viewing a record of this model I want to display the coordinates in the format of "55.0000, -89.5000".
In the default generated CRUD view, currently it displays nothing for this field.

I'm thinking I have to use the mysql `AsText` function somehow, perhaps in `beforeFind()`?

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I found I can get the value to print as "POINT(55.0000, -89.5000)" using the following:

```
public function beforeFind()
{
    parent::beforeFind();

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = "AsText(coordinates) AS coordinates";
    $this->dbCriteria->mergeWith($criteria);
}
```

However, this has the unfortunate side effect of causing all the other fields to be "Not Set".

Answer (score 2):

I guess the default value for `$criteria->select` is `"*"`. By setting `$criteria->select = "AsText(coordinates) AS coordinates"` I was over writing the * and thus only returning the single column.  So what I did was change the line to manually specify the other columns in addition to the coordinates column:

```
$criteria->select = "id,name,street,city,AsText(coordinates) AS coordinates";
```

Not sure if this is the ideal way but it's working for me.  I believe this would be the same thing you'd have to do to use other database functions in the select.